# Google Maps Polyline onclick detect line number

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a google maps polyline

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897), new google.maps.LatLng(29.46758, 88.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(20.46758, 97.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897)];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "rgba(255,0,0, .5)",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4
    });
```

and I created an event (click for example) which displays a box with information. Sample code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(el) {
        var curLat = el.latLng.lat();
        var curLng = el.latLng.lng();
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(curLat,curLng);
        infowindow.content = "<div style= ' width: 200px'>STRING HERE<div>";
        infowindow.setPosition(myLatlng);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });
```

I've defined the `infowindow` globally so I can re-position it.

The problem now is that wherever I click it always displays the same information. Basically what I want to do is to get the line number clicked (starting form 0, 1 ..) and I can use it to get the appropriate data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is not available via the API.

It would be possible to use the geometryy-library(isLocationOnEdge) and iterate over the single lines to detect on which line the click occurs, but I think it's easier to use single Polylines for each segment:

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.46758, 88.027892), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(20.46758, 97.027892), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897)
  ],i=0,infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow;


  while(flightPlanCoordinates.length>1){
    (function(i){
      var segment= new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [flightPlanCoordinates.shift(),flightPlanCoordinates[0]],
        strokeColor: "rgba(255,0,0, .5)",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        map:map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(segment, 'click', function(e){
        infowindow.setOptions({map:map,position:e.latLng,content:'Line#'+i});
      });
    })(i++)
  }
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Do you suggest using single lines instead of build in polylines (In my case I might need up to 1000 lines per displaying map)?

Comment: It may affect the performance(especially dragging/zooming) when you use the single lines, but I don't see a better approach when you need to access a particular segment.